# "Enumerable.cs not found", como ajustar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Após inicializar uma "ContentPage", aparece o seguinte erro: "Enumerable.cs not found".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De fato, não achei o arquivo. A "Enumerable.cs" é exclusiva do "System.Core"? Tentei instalar o "System.Core" mas mostrou uma incompatibilidade que não entendo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso ajustar esse erro ou conseguir instalar a "Enumerable.cs"?

Visual Studio 2015
Xamarin.Forms

Comment: já tentou instalar uma versão anterior da System.Core? Pode ser problema de incompatibilidade. Ou também tenta alterar a versão do .Net

Comment: No meu NuGet aparece somente esta versão da imagem. Não tem anterior.